# How to keep an Android Service always running?

Tags: voip, pjsip

I am building an Android VOIP application that has a service which handles the registration for the client (PJSIP in my case).

For now i am starting a normal service and using the return START_STICKY in order to keep my service up and running all the time since the user needs to be registered 24/7. But that is not the case as i find my self not registered after a while.

What is the best solutions for issues like these?

Make service start in foreground?

I would like to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Could your client simply be 'woken up' when an event (like a call or message) arrives, i.e. use use a push notification system to wake when required? Plus a timer if necessary to reregister if you need to worry about registration timeouts.

Comment: The issue with push notification is that sometime they have delay (queue time), cannot have that delay when a user wants to call the another user. Regarding the Timer, PJSIP has it's own timer, for now i have managed to solve this issue with the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to allow the application keep processor on.